# Woocommerce product bundles doubling

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed the Woocommerce product bundles plugin where I am having issues. For example:

My bundle is setup like:

When you buy Product-A, You can optionally buy Product-B and Product-C in that bundle.

When I purchase 4x Product-A and optionally add 2x Product-B and click add to cart my cart contents/total is

4x Product-A
8x Product-B

It seems as though however many of the parent product there is it will times itself by optional products qty.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this problem.

I looked at wc-pb-cart.php and looked over the function bundle_add_to_cart and came across this:

```
$quantity      = $bundled_item->is_sold_individually() ? 1 : $item_quantity * $bundled_item->get_quantity();
```

So I created my own class and included it within functions.php and then extended WC_PB_Cart and called my new function(same function just removed * $bundled_item->get_quantity() which was causing the duplication.

Then I needed to remove_action on bundle_add_to_cart in my functions.php

```
include 'class-cartFeatures.php';
remove_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', array( WC_PB_Cart::instance(), 'bundle_add_to_cart' ), 10, 6 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', array( new cartFeatures(), 'bundle_add_to_cart_excalibur' ), 10, 6 );
```